# BottomNavbar style in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two questions,

first question:
Why, when I try to use `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` in my bottom navbar, my bar look like this?

[image]

my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            // canvasColor: Colors.transparent

          ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedFontSize: 18,
          unselectedFontSize: 12,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          onTap: (int index){
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right: 10.0)),
                title: Text('MAPS', style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right: 10.0)),
              title: Text('HOME', style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right: 10.0)),
              title: Text('PROFILE', style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
            ),
          ]
        ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

second question: 
How to add outline above my items in navbar, 
and how to change its width, e.g. when you choose `maps`, outline should have e.g. 15px and the other two 5px, etc.

someone like this:
[image]

thanks for any answers :)

Comment: What do you mean by outline? Can you add a picture with the outline?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi i add picture in main post

Comment: The outline is like Tabs' indicator?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi yes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that shadow because the default elevation of BottomNavBar is 8.0 change it to 0.0

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'MAPS',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'HOME',
              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'PROFILE',
              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Output:

[image]

**UPDATE: The scaffold color changing**

```
class New extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewState createState() => _NewState();
}

class _NewState extends State<New> {

  List<Color> scaffoldColors = [Colors.white, Colors.green, Colors.blue];
  List<Widget> bodies = [
    Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("MAP", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("HOME", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("PROFILE", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),
    ),
  ];
  var index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: scaffoldColors[index],
      body: bodies[index],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'MAPS',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'HOME',
              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0)),
            title: Text(
              'PROFILE',
              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, do you know the answer to the second question?

Comment: and i have a problem with your code, because when i click on ```home```(where background is green) my navbar is still white

Comment: Are you changing the color of the nav bar?

Comment: The navbar is not connected to the body of the scaffold...so the color of the scaffold body doesn't affect the nav bar

Comment: If you want the color to change then you have to change the color of the scaffold

Answer (score 0):

First when you use 
`backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` it does not appear to be a problem like you mentioned but when you use `canvasColor: Colors.transparent` its shows exactly like image you have mentiond.

so, you can use

1.`backgroundColor: Colors.transparent`

OR

2.`scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent`